# BERT NER Python

Tags: python, pytorch, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition

I am using BERT model for Named Entity Recognition task.
I have torch version - `1.2.0+cu9.2`
torch vision version - `0.4.0+cu9.2`
Nvidia drivers compatible with cuda 9.2

when i am trying to train my model using the command

```
loss, scores = model(b_input_ids.type(torch.cuda.LongTensor), token_type_ids=None,attention_mask=b_input_mask.to(device), labels=b_labels.type(torch.cuda.LongTensor))
```

i am getting the error below -

```
C:/w/1/s/windows/pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCTensorIndex.cu:361: block: [35,0,0], thread: [0,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
```

Can somebody help me with this one?

Answer (score 1):

A bit of googling provided the [following hint](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/solved-assertion-srcindex-srcselectdimsize-failed-on-gpu-for-torch-cat/1804) with the following suggestions:

> This is due to an out of bounds index in the embedding matrix.

> If you are seeing this error using an nn.Embedding layer, you might add a print statement which shows the min and max values for each input. Some batches might have an out of bounds index.
> Once you find, the erroneous batch you should have a look how it was created so that you can fix this error.

Without seeing your code nobody is going to be able to help more.